# Redirect with htaccess if url of multiple subdomain not contains directory

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdomain

And I have a lot of subdomain: 
sub1.abc.com, sub2.abc.com,.., subn.abc.com with the same directory: true-dir-1, true-dir-2, true-dir-3
I want to
If url not contains (true-dir-1, true-dir-2, true-dir-3) then redirect to subdomain
For example:

```
sub1.abc.com/false-dir redirect to sub1.abc.com
sub2.abc.com/false-dir redirect to sub2.abc.com
```

---

Pls help me use .htaccess to redirect it..
Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub1\.abc\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^true-dir-1 / [L,NC,R=302]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub2\.abc\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^true-dir-2 / [L,NC,R=302]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub3\.abc\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^true-dir-3 / [L,NC,R=302]
```

Comment: I have a lot of subdomain and true-directory

Comment: Right you can but how to get subdir name using your subdomain name?

Comment: You need to place these rules in `DocumentRoot` of each subdomain and make sure these are first rules.

Answer (score 0):

You can use that:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.abc\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^%1 / [L,NC,R=302]
```

Change `[R=302]` for `[R=301]` when test work well.

Comment: Thank you so much. But true directory can be: carsale.html, contact.html, intro.html, product.html .v.v.v Sub domain can be: autopro.abc.com, carone.abc.com, meauto.abc.com ... And the entire subdomain the same true directory.. I tested with one subdomain and one true directory .. but it don't run..

Comment: These are files, not directories. But I change my answer.